# Serial port reading automatically in C#

Tags: c#

Here below is the very simple code for serial port reading automatically:-

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
        //
        // The InitializeComponent() call is required for Windows Forms designer support.
        //
        InitializeComponent();

        //
        // TODO: Add constructor code after the InitializeComponent() call.
        //


        serialPort1.PortName="COM11";
        serialPort1.Open();

    }
    void SerialPort1DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        rtBox.Text="Data Received\n";
    }
    void BtnReadClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rtBox.Text += "Read click" + "\n";
    }
```

System.InvalidOperationException: 跨執行緒作業無效: 存取控制項 'rtBox' 時所使用的執行緒與建立控制項的執行緒不同。

English translation in Google translate from Chinese Characters
"Incomplete thread job: The thread used to access the control 'rtBox' is different from the thread that establishes the control."

Simply I just want to show the message "Data receive" at Rich test box. However, whenever the data receive, there is the following exception:

Do you know why? Thanks

Comment: use control invoke to update in UI thread...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WinForm controls such as your rich text box can only be accessed from the main UI thread. Your serial port object is invoking the event handler from a different one.

You can change your handler to do something like this --

```
void SerialPort1DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        rtBox.Text="Data Received\n";
    }));        
}
```

This will use [Control.Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx) that will then run the inner code in the UI thread.